# Plotting an image at a random position every time user clicks on a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to plot an image at a random position every time the user clicks on a button in my application. (I have made [this video](http://youtu.be/WGnFD4ArHjQ) to illustrate this if it is not clear.)

How to do this?

That I've tried is the following.

```
int num,x,y;
-(IBAction)button{
  num++;
  x = arc4random%320;
  y = arc4random%480;
  UIImageView *flower_xxx;
```

(I want to "xxx" to  like this "flower_%03d,num")

```
  flower_xxx.center = CGPoint(x,y);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please _explain_ what you are trying to do here in your post. Requiring people to go look at a video just to have a clue about what you're asking is not good.

Comment: Sorry, I was bad.

because it is too absurd perception of my Objective-C
So I thought the video was easier to grasp than code.

Comment: You need to post three things: a description of what you are trying to do - must be complete in your post, without external links (that link is fine _in addition_ to the description), the code you have so far, and a description of what doesn't work with that code (error messages, incorrect output/behavior).

Comment: Thank you.
Next time I will describe that way.

Comment: You don't need to remove the link, it _is_ informative. The problem was not the link itself but the lack of explanation inline in your post. Anyway, your question is now much better, thanks for having put the effort into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an example that could use is as follows:

```
...
UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
[im setFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random()%320, arc4random()%460, 20, 20)];
[self.view addSubview:im];
...
```

considers that this is what you put in the event of the button and it randomly places the image within the main view.

also considers that this is an example from which to take inspiration and do something better ^_^

Comment: Thanks so much!and I apologize to everyone. I regret that I did not fully read the description.